# Azure Logic App, can not send message to service Bus

Tags: azure, logic

The send message action always said 
"Message Received could not be parsed and is null"
[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXNxZ.png)

The input is json array.
[Input information and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBdjK.png)

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Post your info on this page (and we need more to help you); do not use links.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out.

Looks like sending a message to service bus requires the message content to be base64 encoded. Since content is a JSON,  need to stringify it explicitly prior to encoding, i.e. use @encodeBase64(string(jsonContent))

Changing the content type to text/plain has the same effect, since in that case the content is treated as a string to begin with.

Comment: this answer should me more prominent than it is :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, I have the json object that I would like to encode. I'm not able to find @encodeBase64 method/function in the editor. Could you please help?